# Function Overloading with Shared Pointers

Tags: c++, overloading, shared-ptr

I had expected this to work but during compiling I get an error, if anyone can point out my mistake or how I should resolve it would be much appreciated. Preferably without resorting to casts. Is there a standard design pattern to do this?

I made a simplified example of my code that shows the problem and my intentions. I have a (normally abstract) base class (shape) with derived classes (Square, Circle). I have shared_ptr references to the objects and want to execute the according functions in a different calls based on the shared_ptr type.

Below is the code that is not working and short of doing dynamic type casting and an ugly if statement I do not know how to correct it.

```
//Standard includes
#include "memory"
#include <typeinfo>

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
};
class Circle : public Shape { };
class Square : public Shape { };

class Logging
{
    static void print(std::shared_ptr<Circle> shape)
    {
        std::cout << "This object is a " << typeid(*shape).name() << std::endl;
    }

    static void print(std::shared_ptr<Square> shape)
    {
        std::cout << "This object is a " << typeid(*shape).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    //Shared Pointer Shape Declaration
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> circle = std::make_shared<Circle>();
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> square = std::make_shared<Square>();

    //Printing Shapes
    Logging::print(circle);     //Compiler ERROR: none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
    Logging::print(square);     //Compiler ERROR: none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Comment: Why did you ecpect this to work? You're passing `std::shared_ptr<Shape>`. You have no overload for that type, or for anything it can be converted to. And the error message does not say "ambiguous call" anywhere.

Comment: The "standard design pattern" is the visitor pattern.

Comment: Smart pointers do not have some sort of automatic downcasting mechanism - if you want to downcast you still have to do it explicitly

Comment: @ molbdnilo, I corrected the "ambiguous call", I will look into the visitor pattern.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the "name" returned by [`std::type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) is not defined and can be whatever the implementor of the standard library feel like. For example a nice name or a variant of the mangled name for the type.

Comment: Btw, in your example case, you may do
    `static void print(std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape)
    {
        assert(shape != nullptr);
        std::cout << "This object is a " << typeid(*shape).name() << std::endl;
    }` (losing `shared_ptr` in naming) as `typeid` works with polymorphic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in downcasting from `std::shared_ptr<Shape>` to `std::shared_ptr<Circle>`. Upcasting when passing to a function, even with smart pointers, is automatic, but not downcasting. So your compiler can't find a print function with this signature:

```
static void Logging::print(std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape);
```

And you have an overload error.

But, since you are using the dereference operator (`*`) inside your function, and since `std::shared_ptr` overload this operator, you can bypass this signature error by using a `template` member function:

Variant of `Logging` `print()` function:

```
class Logging
{
    public:
    template <class T>
    static void print(std::shared_ptr<T> shape)
    {
        std::cout << "This object is a " << typeid(*shape).name() << std::endl;     
    }
};
```

[Here is the example working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8305e1515f5160cb). Just remember that when using templates, that if you are working with smart pointers, use the signature `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

This way, you can avoid using static and dynamic casts.

Comment: As an addendum, if you wanna restrict the Type of T to a class that inherits from T currently you can use BOOST or throw exceptions manually, but in C++20 you'll be able to use Constraints and concepts.
[cpp Reference about this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

Answer (score 1):

Although `Shape`and `Square`are related types, `std::shared_ptr<Shape>` and `std::shared_ptr<Square>` **are not**. That's why there is not any implicit cast between them, so you get a compiler error.

A very classic solution to this would be to delegate the print logic to each class derived from Shape:

```
#include "memory"
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    virtual void print() {}; // empty implementation, you could make it pure virtual as well
};
class Circle : public Shape { 
public:
    virtual void print() override {
        std::cout << "This object is a circle" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Square : public Shape { 
public:
    virtual void print() override {
        std::cout << "This object is a square" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Logging
{
public:
    static void print(std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape) {
        shape->print();
    }
};

int main() {
    //Shared Pointer Shape Declaration
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> circle = std::make_shared<Circle>();
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> square = std::make_shared<Square>();

    //Printing Shapes
    Logging::print(circle);
    Logging::print(square);

    return 0;
}
```

[Working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bcc886e361d84ff)

Note that this is just an example and depending on your actual problem this implementation could not be practical/optimal.

Comment: I had indeed thought about doing it this way. But since I need to implement a lot of functionality I did not want to enlarge my Shape classes in this way.

Comment: I understand. As mentioned in your question comments, the [`Visitor pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can help with that.

Comment: You should never do something like that, that would create a cascade of code for every class that inherits from shape. Template methods exists exactly to that kind of situation, where there is a behavior that is applicable to N classes but is not inherent to them.